# Can I extract optional properties from a type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I wonder if there is a way to extract only properties which are defined as optional in a given type.

```js
type MyType = {
a: number,
optional1?: number,
optional2?: number,
}

// Should be { optional1?: number, optional2?: number }
type OptionalPropertiesOfMyType = ExtractOptionalProperties<T>;

type ExtractOptionalProperties<T> = ??
```

Comment: yes 1sec i'll post a solution

Answer (score 3):

```
type MyType = {
a: number,
optional1?: number,
optional2?: number,
}


type UndefinedKeys<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: undefined extends T[K] ? K : never;
}[keyof T]

type ExtractOptional<T> = Pick<T, Exclude<UndefinedKeys<T>, undefined>>


type Test = ExtractOptional<MyType>
```

this should work let me know

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!
Unfortunately the code doesnt seem to work.. Test seems to equal MyType.
TS version Im using is 2.9.2. But I dont think you are using any syntax that should behave differently in other versions.

Comment: Works correctly, in 2.8.1 should work in 2.9.2; you should end up with
`Pick<MyType, "optional1" | "optional2">` which is equal to `{optional1: number | undefined, optional2: number | undefined}`

Comment: Not working in TS version 5.3.3